# Convert .caf files from stereo to mono

Tags: iphone, audio

How can I convert my .caf sound files, in stereo, to mono ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the terminal issue the following command:

```
afconvert -v -f caff -d ima4 -c 1 sourceFile.caf -o destFile.caf
```

The `-c` options comes from the afconvert help description that you get issuing

```
afconvert -h
```

Comment: WhenI try to use the command:

 afconvert mysourceFile.caf -o mymonosoundfile.caf -f caff -c 1

I'm being prompted to help. I'm making some error ?

Comment: No, it was my fault. I have just edited and updated my answer, which now will work correctly producing a mono caf file which is also compressed (same quality, lower file size).

Comment: That is wonderful, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this for the whole content of a folder...

Comment: Make a python script to walk the directory.